# How do I call emit in solidity from UI

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I have this  function here

```
 function reinvest() onlyDivis public {
        address _customerAddress = msg.sender;
        uint256 _dividends = myDividends(false);
        payoutsTo_[_customerAddress] +=  (int256) (_dividends * magnitude);
        _dividends += referralBalance_[_customerAddress];
        referralBalance_[_customerAddress] = 0;
        uint256 _tokens = purchaseTokens(0x0, _customerAddress, _dividends);
        emit onReinvestment(_customerAddress, _dividends, _tokens);
```

I can call the reinvest function from my UI but how do I use the emit (function) so i can use it to update the Info on my UI?

Comment: you need to setup a listener  for the event onReinvestment on the web3 contract-instance object

Answer (score 0):

emitting events is actually a very good approach to, later on, search for something.

So good, that some people developer [ethql](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethql) and there's even [TheGraph](https://thegraph.com/).

But while those two might seem a bit complex at first, you can very easily do what you want by using [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html#event-emitter).

Here's an example

```
let tx = await contractWithSigner.setValue("I like turtles.");

contract.on("ValueChanged", (author, oldValue, newValue, event) => {
  // Called when anyone changes the value

  console.log(author);
  // "0x14791697260E4c9A71f18484C9f997B308e59325"

  console.log(oldValue);
  // "Hello World"

  console.log(newValue);
  // "Ilike turtles."

  // See Event Emitter below for all properties on Event
  console.log(event.blockNumber);
  // 4115004
});
await tx.wait();
```

Using the following contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SimpleStorage {

  event ValueChanged(address indexed author, string oldValue, string newValue);

  string _value;

  constructor(string value) public {
    emit ValueChanged(msg.sender, _value, value);
    _value = value;
  }

  function getValue() view public returns (string) {
    return _value;
  }

  function setValue(string value) public {
    emit ValueChanged(msg.sender, _value, value);
    _value = value;
  }
}
```